# Problema com tomcat

Tags: tomcat

Estou utilizando o netbeans, maven, hibernate e mysql, criei apenas um projeto simples Maven, e estou tentando mapear uma classe, e notei que o tomcat não inicializa corretamente qualquer projeto que executo.

Este é o log:

> Using CATALINA_BASE:
>   "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.27.0_base"
>   Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Program Files\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Apache Tomcat 8.0.27" Using CATALINA_TMPDIR:
>   "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.27.0_base\temp"
>   Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111" Using
>   CLASSPATH:       "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache
>   Tomcat 8.0.27\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Apache Tomcat 8.0.27\bin\tomcat-juli.jar" 01-Sep-2017
>   21:15:01.560 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version: 
>   Apache Tomcat/8.0.27 01-Sep-2017 21:15:01.560 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:
>   Sep 28 2015 08:17:25 UTC 01-Sep-2017 21:15:01.560 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:
>   8.0.27.0 01-Sep-2017 21:15:01.560 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:
>   Windows 10 01-Sep-2017 21:15:01.560 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:
>   10.0 01-Sep-2017 21:15:01.560 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:
>   amd64 01-Sep-2017 21:15:01.560 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:
>   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre 01-Sep-2017 21:15:01.560 INFO
>   [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM
>   Version:           1.8.0_111-b14 01-Sep-2017 21:15:01.560 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:
>   Oracle Corporation 01-Sep-2017 21:15:01.560 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:
>   C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.27.0_base
>   01-Sep-2017 21:15:01.560 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:
>   C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 8.0.27
>   01-Sep-2017 21:15:01.560 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1|DESKTOP-N0RMD2I
>   01-Sep-2017 21:15:01.560 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument:
>   -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.27.0_base\conf\logging.properties
>   01-Sep-2017 21:15:01.560 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument:
>   -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager 01-Sep-2017 21:15:01.560 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Apache Tomcat 8.0.27\endorsed 01-Sep-2017 21:15:01.560 INFO
>   [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command
>   line argument:
>   -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.27.0_base
>   01-Sep-2017 21:15:01.560 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Apache Tomcat 8.0.27 01-Sep-2017 21:15:01.560 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument:
>   -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.27.0_base\temp
>   01-Sep-2017 21:15:01.560 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR
>   based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in
>   production environments was not found on the java.library.path:
>   C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS
>   Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program
>   Files\Samsung\SamsungLink\AllShare Framework DMS\bin\;C:\Program
>   Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;.
>   01-Sep-2017 21:15:02.075 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler
>   ["http-nio-8084"] 01-Sep-2017 21:15:02.466 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a
>   shared selector for servlet write/read 01-Sep-2017 21:15:02.482 INFO
>   [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing
>   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"] 01-Sep-2017 21:15:02.482 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a
>   shared selector for servlet write/read 01-Sep-2017 21:15:02.482 INFO
>   [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization
>   processed in 2001 ms 01-Sep-2017 21:15:02.560 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting
>   service Catalina 01-Sep-2017 21:15:02.560 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet
>   Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.27 01-Sep-2017 21:15:02.575 INFO
>   [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying
>   configuration descriptor
>   C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.27.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost\almoxarifado.xml
>   01-Sep-2017 21:15:04.388 INFO [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was
>   scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this
>   logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were
>   found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve
>   startup time and JSP compilation time. 01-Sep-2017 21:15:04.607 INFO
>   [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of
>   configuration descriptor
>   C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.27.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost\almoxarifado.xml
>   has finished in 2,032 ms 01-Sep-2017 21:15:04.607 INFO
>   [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying
>   configuration descriptor
>   C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.27.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost\manager.xml
>   01-Sep-2017 21:15:04.997 INFO [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was
>   scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this
>   logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were
>   found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve
>   startup time and JSP compilation time. 01-Sep-2017 21:15:05.029 INFO
>   [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of
>   configuration descriptor
>   C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.27.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost\manager.xml
>   has finished in 422 ms 01-Sep-2017 21:15:05.076 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler
>   ["http-nio-8084"] 01-Sep-2017 21:15:05.091 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler
>   ["ajp-nio-8009"] 01-Sep-2017 21:15:05.107 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 2621 ms

Se alguém puder ajudar agradeço muito!